# Losе links at multiprocessing parsing on Python (selenium/phantomJS/ProcessPoolExecutor)

Tags: python, parsing, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, multiprocessing

(Sorry for my English)
I want to make parser for some website with include a lot of JS scripts,
for this I use selenium+phantomjs+lxml. Needs that this parser works fast,
at least 1000 links per 1 hour. For this purpose I use multiprocessing
(not Threading!! because GIL) and module Future, and ProcessExecutorPool.

The problem in next, when I give to input list from 10 links and 5 workers, after executions 
lose some links. It can be 1 links or greater(till 6! - the max value but rare). This of course bad result. 
There is some dependence, for increasing amount of process, increase amount of lost links. 
First of all I trace where program breaking. (asserts doesn't works correctly because multiprocessing)
I find that, the program breaking after string "browser.get(l)". Then I put time.sleep(x) - give some time 
for downloading page. Give no result. Then I try research .get() from selenium.webdriver....remote.webdriver.py
but it's reload .execute() - and this function takes so many parameters - and discovers it - too long and 
difficult for me... and the same time I try to run program for 1 process - and I lost 1 links. I thought, may
be problem not in selenium and PhantomJS, than I replace concurrent.futures.Future.ProcessExecutorPool
on multiprocessing.Pool - problem solves, links don't lose, but if amount of process - <= 4, works 
almost good, but some time appeares new mistakes(this mistakes appears when set  4 <= amount of process):

```
    """
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 119, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
File "interface.py", line 34, in hotline_to_mysql
    w = Parse_hotline().browser_manipulation(link)
File "/home/water/work/parsing/class_parser/parsing_classes.py", line 352, in browser_manipulation
    browser.get(l)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 247, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 233, in execute
    response = self.command_executor.execute(driver_command, params)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 401, in execute
    return self._request(command_info[0], url, body=data)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/remote_connection.py", line 471, in _request
    resp = opener.open(request, timeout=self._timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 463, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 481, in _open
    '_open', req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1210, in http_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 1185, in do_open
    r = h.getresponse()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 1171, in getresponse
    response.begin()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 351, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/client.py", line 321, in _read_status
    raise BadStatusLine(line)
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "interface.py", line 69, in <module>
    main()
File "interface.py", line 63, in main
    executor.map(hotline_to_mysql, link_list)
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 260, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 599, in get
    raise self._value
http.client.BadStatusLine: ''
"""


import random
import time
import lxml.html as lh
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
from multiprocessing import Pool
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from concurrent.futures import Future, ProcessPoolExecutor, ThreadPoolExecutor
AMOUNT_PROCESS = 5

def parse(h)->list:
    # h - str, html of page
    lxml_ = lh.document_fromstring(h)
    name = lxml_.xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div[6]/ul/li[1]/a/@title')
    prices_ = (price.text_content().strip().replace('\xa0', ' ')
                for price in lxml_.xpath('//*[@id="gotoshop-price"]'))
    markets_ =(market.text_content().strip() for market in
            lxml_.find_class('cell shop-title'))
    wares = [[name[0], market, price] for (market, price)
            in zip(markets_, prices_)]
    return wares


def browser_manipulation(l):
    #options =  []
    #options.append('--load-images=false')
    #options.append('--proxy={}:{}'.format(host, port))
    #options.append('--proxy-type=http')
    #options.append('--user-agent={}'.format(user_agent)) #тут хедеры рандомно

    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    #user agent takes from my config.py
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (random.choice(USER_AGENT))
    browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    #print(browser)
    #print('~~~~~~', l)
    #browser.implicitly_wait(20)
    #browser.set_page_load_timeout(80)
    #time.sleep(2)
    browser.get(l)
    time.sleep(20)
    result = parse(browser.page_source)
    #print('++++++', result[0][0])
    browser.quit()
    return result

def main():
    #open some file with links

    with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
        link_list = [i.replace('\n', '') for i in f]
    with Pool(AMOUNT_PROCESS) as executor:
        executor.map(browser_manipulation, link_list)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Where is the problem(selenium+phantomJS, ThreadPoolExecutor, my code)? Why links lost?
How to increase speed of parsing?
Finally, may be there are alternative way for parse dynamic website without selenium+phantomjs, on python?
Of course, important is speed of parsing.
Thank's for answers.

Answer (score 0):

I try, instead ProcessPoolExecutor - ThreadPoolExecutor, losing links stop. In Thread... case, speed approximately equal to Process.

The question is actual, if you have some information about this, please write. Thanks.